Can I control a Constraint Influece property from a geometry node?
I'm using a custom property to control the state of an object. If the property is set to 1, the object is set to one location, and if it's set to 0, the object is set to a different location.
When the object is moved to one location, I want to set the influence value of a "Child Of" constraint to 1, so that it is influenced by the Bone it is moved to (and set the influence to 0 when the property is switched) Does anyone have a way I can do this? Or if Geometry Nodes are even the right way to go?
If this doesn't make sense, let me know so I can try to add more detail.

You could use drivers to connect one value to another. Does it answer your question ?

I'm new to Blender, so I didn't know what drivers were, but I did some research and found a way to use them to solve this! Thanks so much!

I cleared keyframes, then added drivers connected to the custom property to change the constraint influence

